# Is convolution jointly continuous on $\mathcal{E}'$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with its usual strong topology (being the dual space of $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R})$). Is convolution jointly continuous on $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is Théorème IV in §3 of Chapitre VI (page 157) in Laurent Schwartz's *Théorie des distributions*.